# jQuery Hover Over Image Content Only and Not Alpha

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

Perhaps the title isn't great, but I had a little trouble with the wording...

Basically, is it possible to have jQuery's hover only fire over the actual content of a png with an alpha channel.

So in the image below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G4fY.png

Only fire on the rectangle and not the  alpha channel which make up the rest of the document bounds...

I've tried the obvious $('obj').hover(function(){stuff}) but this fires on the alpha channel too...

The final implementation of this will be for more complex shapes than just a rotated square, so css3 tricks are out for the primary basis, but could be used with a back-up/shim, plus I need to support IE7 and ipad,iphone,ipod....

If there is a CSS2 solution then that would be suitable too. Also any real guidance on this issue is more than welcome. 
My backup for this will be to have an empty div, display block and position it over the shape and then use that. This will obviously not be ideal for the less square objects.

Any hits or tips are more than welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible depending on the stacking context of your elements.  Keep in mind that when you do a focus over any particular element on a page, that you are actually focusing all other elements within the same stacking context.

So what you could do is either stop the event from bubbling up the stack (if the element you want to "hover" is lower in the stack that the elements you want to prevent hover effects on), or specifically put in prevent default for onhover events for all elements in the stacking context except for the one you want to actually get a hover effect.

Comment: Hi,I'm struggling to understand your answer within the context of my problem. Where would I attach the event to? and what are the other items in the stack that I would prevent from firing? Also how can I have a non-square hit area for the hover area? Thank you

Comment: Ahh. I guess I wasn;t clear on your original intent. In your case you may want to use a map tag to define the non-square area that you want to make hoeverable.  Then you could Use jquery to bind hover event to that areamap.

Comment: Hi. Nice suggestion. I will implement it and update this post, assuming all goes well you should post an updated answer for acceptance ;). Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi yeah just finished implementing it. I used http://bit.ly/39UzF2 to speed up the complicated mapping. I needed to use the JS onmouseover and out to trigger some jQuery rather than being able to do it all with pure CSS as the <map><area> thing is just a solid area with coords rather than separate areas. Thanks for your help and if you wanna post a changed answer to help others I will upvote it :-) Cheers